# Android - Do I need to target same play service version for App and wear?

Tags: android, google-play-services, wear-os

I have recently updated my app and wear's google play services version from 9.x to 11.x in build.gradle. I have no issues with the app itself. But I'm having issues with wear device which fails to establish connection with the App on mobile.

I checked to downgrade playservices to 9.x on wear and it seems working.

I'm not sure how often wear devices get updated with the google play services. Is it tied to the OS update itself? Based on wear OS play services are restricted from updating?

This might be a bit of dumb question but I'm trying to understand the relation between wear OS and play services.

Any information related to this is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I think it's better to keep the version the same.

Comment: yes you need to keep same version for google play services some time may  lead to crash.

Comment: @Jintin  I'll downgrade play services version then. Do you have any idea about the play services update's on wear's? Is this silent push just like the mobile and can we expect most of the wearbles to be on latest play services version?

Comment: @ParasSantoki Any idea about my comment above?

Comment: suppose your mobile app play services version is
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.6.2'

then Wear version like this
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:11.6.2'

Not latest version
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:11.8.0'

Answer (score 0):

```
suppose your mobile app google play services version is
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.6.2'

Then Wear version should be like this
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:11.6.2'

Not latest version of google play services
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:11.8.0'
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. My question is more over how frequently Android wear updates google play services. I am sure that mobile updates silently as soon as we are connected to network and want to know if this is the same behaviour for wear